# Howto override the event timestamp set by WSO2DAS

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

Currently WSO2 Data Analytic Server set the current timestamp to every event received using the available APIs. Is there a way to pass the timestamp value on the event data over the APIs in order to sent historical events to DAS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From DAS 3.1.0 RC 1 onwards this can be achieved. You can follow the steps below to try it out.

1. Download DAS 3.1.0 RC1 from [here](https://github.com/wso2/product-das/releases/tag/v3.1.0-RC1).
2. Create an event stream with your payload and also add an attribute named **_timestamp** and set the attribute type as **long**.
3. Persist the Event selecting your payload attributes. (Please note that you will not be able to select the _timestamp attribute so leave it as it is)
4. Now simulate a event by providing your payload data along with the _timestamp epoch e.g - 1450206041000. The data explorer will show you an event received in 2015-12-16 00:30:41

Comment: I wait for the 3.1.0 release and test this. The timestamp is set correctly but i notice a few quirks. The eventsink component process events in a positional form. Therefore if the stream definition has the _timestamp attribute before the others the timestamp value will appear in the analytics table as the value of another attribute and all the others will be shifted. So as a practical recommendation to anyone using this feature:  add the _timestamp attribute as the last one on the stream.